# Find a common commit in two completely different git trees

Tags: git, bash, git-rebase, cvs2git

The following script tries to find the newest common commit of two branches. The commits should have the same *subject*, same *author* and same *author date*. but *commit date* and *hash* are different. Because of this, `git rebase` cannot find this branch automatically.

```
#!/bin/bash
lastbr=
lastrest=
revU=  # Update
revB=  # Base
rm -f rev.*.tmp
(
  git log --format='format:b %H %at %an %ae %f' master
  echo
  git log --format='format:u %H %at %an %ae %f' master_tmpnew
) | sort -r -t' ' -k3 | while read br rev rest; do
  echo "? $br $rev $rest"
  [ "$br" != "u" ] || revU="$rev"
  [ "$br" != "b" ] || revB="$rev"
  if [ "$lastrest" = "$rest" -a "$lastbr" != "$br" ]; then
    echo "found match: base $revB  updae $revU"
    echo "$revB" >rev.base.tmp
    echo "$revU" >rev.update.tmp
    break
  fi
  lastrest="$rest"
  lastbr="$br"
done
if [ ! -f rev.base.tmp ]; then
  echo "No matching revision found"
  exit 1
fi
revB="`cat rev.base.tmp`"
revU="`cat rev.update.tmp`"
git rebase --onto $revB $revU master_tmpnew
```

**The question:** This solution doesn't look very nice to me. Does anyone of you have a better idea how to implement this problem or is there already a solution available?

**The background:** I try to implement an incremental CVS-to-GIT import using the tool [cvs2git](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2git.html). Officially, it doesn't support incremental imports, but I found a solution which is similar to [this workaround](http://www.oak.homeunix.org/~marcel/blog/2009/06/03/tracking-cvs-with-git-using-cvs2git). The only problem: I had problems doing a simple `git rebase`. Because the branches don't match together (different hash & commit dates due to the nature of git2svn), it often rewrites more commits than necessary if I use it without detailed references (the common commit). Check [this](http://pastebin.com/jFfnVaQj) for a ready-to-run test scenario of the script above.

Comment: Instead of `$revB`, I should probably use `master` for the rebase command: `git rebase --onto master $revU master_tmpnew`. But this is not subject of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps git-cherry can be of use. It will compare the change sets rather than commit hash to determine whether or not two commits contain the same thing.

http://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry.html

Comment: Thank you for pushing me to the right trace. Over the manual, I found the commands git-cherry, git-patch-id and git-cherry-pick now, all of them very interesting. Finally, I was able to replace the code above with this command line:

`git cherry-pick $( git cherry master master_tmpnew | grep '^+' | cut -d' ' -f2) `

Comment: Cool. Happy that I could help.